# Using lstenvironment in another environment

Tags: listings, environments, nesting

The following simple latex code doesn't seem to work for me and there seems to be no reason why:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{deflist}[2][]{%
    \renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{{#2} ::=}%
    \lstset{numbers=left,basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}%
}{}
\newenvironment{test}[2]{%
    #1
    \begin{deflist}{#2}%
}{\end{deflist}}

\begin{document}
\begin{deflist}{sometest}
Some Item
Some other item
\end{deflist}
\begin{test}{title}{sometest}
Some Item
Some other item
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

What I want to achive: I want an environment where every line is preceded by `#1 ::=` in order to write EBNF rules efficiently. This is what the environment `deflist` does. Then I want to nest it inside another environement that automatically adds a title for the rule (probably some other things like breaking before, etc.).

The code above fails and doesn't even issue an error for me. If you still want to read the whole log click [here (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/DCu66ss3).

Comment: You can use `title={...}` directly.

Comment: Nesting `verbatim`-like environments is not possible, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks @PaulGessler for explaining what the .log doesn't explain, that sure helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `title` key directly in

```
\lstnewenvironment{deflist}[3][]{%
    \renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{{#3} ::=}%
    \lstset{numbers=left,basicstyle=\ttfamily,title={#2},#1}%
}{}
```

then use

```
\begin{deflist}[optional]{title}{sometest}
```

If no title is needed use

```
\begin{deflist}{}{sometest}
```

On the other hand, if you don't like typing `{}`, you can make a new environment with *two* optional arguments using `xparse` package (I didn't do it now).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{deflist}[3][]{%
    \renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{{#3} ::=}%
    \lstset{numbers=left,basicstyle=\ttfamily,title={#2},#1}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{deflist}{}{sometest}
Some Item
Some other item
\end{deflist}
\begin{deflist}{title}{sometest}
Some Item
Some other item
\end{deflist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Minor typo: it's `xparse` instead of `xprase` :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina hihi, thanks. I do lot of them. :-)